# NativeScript CLI basics: No main-page.xml or app.css file after setup

Tags: command-line-interface, nativescript

Following the setup instructions to get my first android app up and running I hit a snag in the section "Exercise: Try Livesync". I do not see a main-page.xml or app.css file in my project.

Comment: Can you outline the steps that you took and then also copy-paste the structure and files that were generated?

Answer (score 0):

The text editor I was using may have been the problem. When I repeated the steps and used php storm all of the files were there. Looks like it is home-page instead of main-page though.